# Object reference required for non static field

Tags: c#, webforms, innerhtml

I use the inner html method to render a page but as soon as I put the id name inside a **static method** I get an compilation error that states that an object reference is required for a non static field.

Example

```
<div id="TopicHeader">
</div>
```

Code behind

```
topicGenerator.InnerHtml += "<div class='topicGenSpacing'><ul>";
```

This works find just as long as I dont place it inside a method.

Is there a way of overcoming this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to pass `topicGenerator` as a parameter of your static method.

Or remove the `static` keyWord if your method is inside of a class where `topicGenerator` is defined as a private field (for example).

Answer (score 1):

You *probabbly* put that code inside a `static` method, so you have to provide a *concrete* instance where `topicGenerator` is.